# Ansible modules parameter syntax

Tags: ansible, ansible-module

Why is it that on the `playbook.yml` under the command task to be executed, some modules have a quotation mark while some does not?

For example, if you check the syntax below, the module `line` is with embedded in a quotation mark but `script` is not.

```yaml
- name: 'Execute a script on all web server nodes and start httpd service'
  hosts: web_nodes

  tasks:

    - name: 'Update entry into /etc/resolv.conf'
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/resolv.conf
        line: 'nameserver 10.1.250.10' 

    - name: 'Execute a script'
      script: /tmp/install_script.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Both modules take as parameter for [`line`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#parameter-line) or [`cmd`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/script_module.html#parameter-cmd) a string.

> Why is it that ... some modules have a quotation mark while some does not?

Your question is about the [YAML Syntax](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html)

> which is how Ansible playbooks (our configuration management language) are expressed.

[when to quote](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#when-to-quote-variables-a-yaml-gotcha) and [YAML Gotchas](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html#gotchas)

> While you can put just about anything into an unquoted scalar, there are some exceptions.

Also a style guide can be a reason of different ways of when and how to quote.